# Something like invalidate(), but not deleting the bitmap, just redrawing it somewhere else

Tags: java, bitmap, ondraw, invalidation

I need something that would draw bitmaps every.. lets say half a second on random coordinates.
Basicly how a simple updated javascript canvas would work.

I am using setContentView and onDraw and in onDraw I am using invalidate();
I like invalidate, but I need it not to delete the bitmap, after it redraws it.

Edit here is the code:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.draw(canvas);
    Random rand = new Random();
    int  n = rand.nextInt(Functions.hit);
    canvas.drawBitmap(MainActivity.dot,Functions.Pixels_x.get(n), Functions.Pixels_y.get(n), null);     
    try {Thread.sleep(delay);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}    
    invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Edited the original post with it.